# especificar otro id por uno personalizado

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy usando una base de datos previamente creada y el id de la tabla se llama `"idempresa"`, ¿Como podría especificarle a `rails` que el `id` lo va a guardar en ese campo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a usar

```
class Modelo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "idempresa"
end
```

Mas info de las convenciones de nombre que puedes sobrescribir en:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions